# Can someone help me to find a study/dataset of height differnces of men and women including normal distributions and their standard deviation/s?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, dataset

i am currently interested in a study or a valid data set of height differences of men and women. What I am explicitly looking for is something with normal distributions and their standard deviation/s. But unfortunately i couldn't find something like that so I thought maybe someone can help me here =)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [This page](https://ourworldindata.org/human-height) has some relevant data. Most data on the Internet for the general public is better at giving means than standard deviations. Standard deviations (mostly about 2.5-3.5 inches) can often be estimated from graphs. // Unless heights are restricted to by sport, gender, and age group, most distributions are mixtures of normal distributions, which are nearly but not exactly normal. Heights of men and women may differ by 1.5 SD, so mix has noticeably flat peaks. (If dif in means > 2 SD, then mixture dist'n is bimodal.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "with normal distribution". Data can at best be approximately normal (heights can only be positive and for that reason can never be normal). What data count as "approximately normal" is a controversial issue and ultimately subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mixture distributions** of normal heights are not necessarily normal.

(1) 50:50 mixture: $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 65, \sigma=2.5)$
and $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu =69, \sigma=3.5).$ Flat mode and moderately skewed.

```
curve(.5*dnorm(x,65,2.5)+.5*dnorm(x,69,3), 55, 80, lwd=2, 
      ylab="Density", xlab="Height",
      main="Mixture of Two Normal Distn's: Flat mode")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 curve(.5*dnorm(x,65,2.5), add=T, lty="dotted", col="blue")
 curve(.5*dnorm(x,69,3), add=T, lty="dotted", col="brown")
```

[image]

(2) 50:50 mixture: $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 63, \sigma=3)$
and $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu =70, \sigma=3).$ Bimodal

```
curve(.5*dnorm(x,63,3)+.5*dnorm(x,70,3), 55, 80, lwd=2, 
      ylab="Density", xlab="Height",
      main="Mixture of Two Normal Distn's: Bimodal")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 curve(.5*dnorm(x,63,3), add=T, lty="dotted", col="blue")
 curve(.5*dnorm(x,70,3), add=T, lty="dotted", col="brown")
```

[image]

*Note:* "Merging" two populations results in a population with a mixture distribution. By contrast. the *sum* of two normal random variables is always normal.